# Apache ReverseProxy Netscaler Gateway abort request because invalid characters in Set-Cookie

Tags: apache, mod-proxy, netscaler

I have an apache, which works as reverse proxy for a Netscale Gateway. Sometimes it works, but in many cases the request ends with a 500. The log always give the same error type:

```
[Mon Aug 20 12:51:24.541905 2018] [http:error] [pid 4919:tid 140600024221440] [client 192.168.22.194:40187] AH02430: Response header 'Set-Cookie' value of 'NSC_TASS=\x0fi\xd4a\xbd\x8e\xcf\xdek\x18\xcd:\x01\xc6d\xf1\xe6;HttpOnly;Path=/;Secure' contains invalid characters, aborting request
[Mon Aug 20 13:03:09.550947 2018] [http:error] [pid 5023:tid 140354590320384] [client 192.168.22.194:24541] AH02430: Response header 'Set-Cookie' value of 'NSC_TASS=le8M1TpPxu5GG1h8nEom8vsA\xe3\x06\x87\x8fnId=&janusWebEvent=PDClass.getJanusServerPage_webEvent_nextPhaseGC2%2C114078_pid_pdPreview_imgPath_res133136%2Fimg%2F_cid_10_clName_ADV_oidHi_10_oidLow_114073;HttpOnly;Path=/;Secure' contains invalid characters, aborting request
[Mon Aug 20 13:09:15.239058 2018] [http:error] [pid 5330:tid 140134346917632] [client 192.168.22.194:40606] AH02430: Response header 'Set-Cookie' value of 'NSC_TASS=\x95\x15\xa91e\xf8\xc8\x96\xdfI\x02\x89\xf4y\x05\xf2&;HttpOnly;Path=/;Secure' contains invalid characters, aborting request
```

I think it is the backslash in the cookie value, because backslashes are not allowed.
Can apache skip the validating of this or can I write a rule to rewrite the cookie value to a url-encoding\utf-8... value?

My config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> # a balancer managed the ssl
    ServerName ng.subdomain.domain.tld
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLProxyVerify none 
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
    ProxyRequests Off
    #ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass / https://ng.domain2.tld/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://ng.domain2.tld/
    #ProxyPass / wss://ng.domain2.tld/
    #ProxyPassReverse / wss://ng.domain2.tld/


    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain ng.subdomain.domain.tld ng.domain2.tld
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can set the HttpProtocolOptions to LenientMethods, it might be set at Strict by default. This will only work if your proxy targter returns 501 for invalid restuls.

For more information see the [Apache documentation on HttpProtocolOptions](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#httpprotocoloptions).

Comment: Tried it (in different combinations and locations), but see no difference. :(

Answer (score 0):

An easy fix would be to simply have the netscaler encrypt its session cookies.

https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX220162

Answer (score 0):

To Encrypt session cookies as suggested above:

set lb parameter -useSecuredPersistenceCookie Enabled-cookiePassphrase

Example :

set lb parameter -useSecuredPersistenceCookie Enabled-cookiePassphrase test